# React Component not rendered properly with Turbolinks in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, turbolinks

I have a very simple Rails app with a react component that just displays "Hello" in an existing *div element* in a particular page (let's say the *show* page).

When I load the related page using its URL, it works. I see *Hello* on the page.

However, when I'm previously on another page (let's say the *index* page and then I go to the *show* page using Turbolinks, well, the component is not rendered, unless I go back and forth again. (going back to the *index* Page and coming back to the *show* page)

From here every time I go back and forth, I can say that the view is rendered twice more time.
Not only twice but twice more time! (i.e. 2 times then 4, then 6 etc..)

I know that since in the same time I set the content of the `div` I output a message to the console.

In fact I guess that going back to the *index* page should still run the component code without the display since the *div element* is not on the *index* page. But why in a cumulative manner?

The problems I want to solve are:

1. To get the code run on the first request of the *show* page
2. To block the code from running in other pages (including the *index* page)
3. To get the code run once on subsequent requests of the *show* page

---

Here the exact steps and code I used *(I'll try to be as concise as possible.)*

- I have a Rails 5.1 app with react installed with:

  ```
  rails new myapp --webpack=react
  ```
- I then create a simple *Item* scaffold to get some pages to play with:

  ```
  rails generate scaffold Item name
  ```
- I just add the following *div element* in the *Show* page (`app/views/items/show.html.erb`):

  ```
  <div id=hello></div>
  ```
- *Webpacker* already generated a *Hello* component (`hello_react.jsx`) that I modified as following in ordered to use the above *div element*. I changed the original `'DOMContentLoaded'` *event*:

  ```
  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    console.log("DOM loaded..");
    var element = document.getElementById("hello");
    if(element) {
      ReactDOM.render(<Hello name="React" />, element)
    }
  })
  ```
- I then added the following *webpack* script tag at the bottom of the previous *view* (`app/views/items/show.html.erb`):

  ```
  <%= javascript_pack_tag("hello_react") %>
  ```
- I then run the `rails server` and the `webpack-dev-server` using `foreman start` (installed by adding `gem 'foreman'` in the `Gemfile`) . Here is the content of the `Procfile` I used:

  ```
  web:     bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
  webpack: bin/webpack-dev-server --port 8080 --hot
  ```

---

And here are the steps to follow to reproduce the described behavior:

1. Load the *index* page using the URL `http://localhost:3000/items`
2. Click *New Item* to add a new item. Rails redirects to the item's *show* page at the URL `localhost:3000/items/1`. Here we can see the *Hello React!* message. It works well!
3. Reload the *index* page using the URL `http://localhost:3000/items`. The item is displayed as expected.
4. Reload the *show* page using the URL `http://localhost:3000/items/1`. The *Hello* message is displayed as expected with one console message.
5. Reload the *index* page using the URL `http://localhost:3000/items`
6. Click to the *Show* link *(should be performed via turbolink)*. The message is **not** shown neither the console message.
7. Click the *Back* link *(should be performed via turbolink)* to go to the *index* page.
8. Click again to the *Show* link *(should be performed via turbolink)*. This time the message is well displayed. The console message for its part is shown **twice**.

From there each time I go back to the *index* and come back again to the *show* page displays two more messages at the console each time.

Note: Instead of using (and replacing) a particular *div* element, if I let the original `hello_react` file that append a *div* element, this behavior is even more noticeable.

Edit: Also, if I change the `link_to` links by including `data: {turbolinks: false}`. It works well. Just as we loaded the pages using the URLs in the browser address bar.

---

I don't know what I'm doing wrong..

Any ideas?

Edit: I put the code in the following repo if interested to try this:
https://github.com/sanjibukai/react-turbolinks-test

Comment: Are you able to put a demo on GitHub? I suspect the problem is a result of adding an event handler every time the show page loads, and not removing that when it unloads. I should be able to give a fuller answer if I could look at the project in full.

Comment: @DomChristie Yep, I'll try to put the full repo.. Yet the steps are actually exhaustive. Nothing less, nothing more..

Comment: @DomChristie Hi, Here is the Github repo for the code https://github.com/sanjibukai/react-turbolinks-test Thank you very much for considering this problem..

Comment: I am struggling with a similar issue. Would skipping turbolinks, ie: `rails new app --skip-turbolinks` solve the issue completely?

Answer (score 6):

This is quite a complex issue, and I am afraid I don't think it has a straightforward answer. I will explain as best I can!

> - To get the code run on the first request of the show page

Your `turbolinks:load` event handler is not running because your code is run *after* the `turbolinks:load` event is triggered. Here is the flow:

1. User navigates to show page
2. `turbolinks:load` triggered
3. Script in body evaluated

So the `turbolinks:load` event handler won't be called (and therefore your React component won't be rendered) until the next page load.

To (partly) solve this you could remove the `turbolinks:load` event listener, and call `render` directly:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="React" />,
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
)
```

Alternatively you could use `<%= content_for … %>`/`<%= yield %>` to insert the script tag in the `head`. e.g. in your application.html.erb layout

```
…
<head>
  …
  <%= yield :javascript_pack %>
  …
</head>
…
```

then in your show.html.erb:

```
<%= content_for :javascript_pack, javascript_pack_tag('hello_react') %>
```

In both cases, it is worth nothing that for any HTML you add to the page with JavaScript in a `turbolinks:load` block, you should remove it on `turbolinks:before-cache` to prevent  duplication issues when revisiting pages. In your case, you might do something like:

```
var div = document.createElement('div')

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="React" />,
  document.body.appendChild(div)
)

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:before-cache', function () {
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div)
})
```

Even with all this, you may still encounter duplication issues when revisiting pages. I believe this is to do with the way in which previews are rendered, but I have not been able to fix it without disabling previews.

> - To get the code run once on subsequent requests of the show page
> - To block the code from running in other pages (including the index page)

As I have mentioned above, including page-specific scripts dynamically can create difficulties when using Turbolinks. Event listeners in a Turbolinks app behave very differently to that without Turbolinks, where each page gets a new `document` and therefore the event listeners are removed automatically. Unless you manually remove the event listener (e.g. on `turbolinks:before-cache`), every visit to that page will add yet another listener. What's more, if Turbolinks has cached that page, a `turbolinks:load` event will fire twice: once for the cached version, and another for the fresh copy. This is probably why you were seeing it rendered 2, 4, 6 times.

With this in mind, my best advice is to avoid adding page-specific scripts to run page-specific code. Instead, include all your scripts in your application.js manifest file, and use the elements on your page to determine whether a component gets mounted. Your example does something like this in the comments:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  var element = document.getElementById("hello");
  if(element) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Hello name="React" />, element)
  }
})
```

If this is included in your application.js, then any page with a `#hello` element will get the component.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi @Dom and thanks; this last code snippet is `jsx` and I'm unable to add it to the *application.js* manifest file.. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: I'm afraid that architecting web packs is beyond me, but you might want to try `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` in your application layout `head`, then `import './hello_react'` in app/javascript/packs/application. As I said, I'm not an expert web pack strategies, so I won't make this part of my answer, but hope that helps get you started.

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with similar problem (`link_to` helper method was changing URL but react content was not loaded; had to refresh page manually to load it properly). After some googling I've found simple workaround on [this page](https://codefor.life/turbolinks-5-rails-5-not-that-bad/).

```
<%= link_to "Foo", new_rabbit_path(@rabbit), data: { turbolinks: false } %>
```

Since this causes a full page refresh when the link is clicked, now my react pages are loaded properly. Maybe you will find it useful in your project as well :)

Comment: This is the solution, not just work-around. However it needs more self-explanation.
So far Rails has turbolinks loading on top to control the page rendering by pushing rendered HTML on navigation. The script that we call some events eg `DOMContentLoaded` for rendering DOM will not work under turbolinks.
Turn turbolinks off for the navigation, perhaps to a SPA, solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Upon what you said I tested some code.

First, I simply [pull out the `ReactDOM.render` method](https://github.com/sanjibukai/react-turbolinks-test/commit/b08020ccb22e7eddce611930c2c282ea313acff3) from the listener as you suggested in your first snippet.

This provide a big step forward since the message is no longer displayed elsewhere (like in the *index* page) but only in the *show* page as wanted.

But something interesting happen in the *show* page. There is **no more accumulation** of the message as appended *div* element, which is good. In fact it's even displayed **once** as wanted. But.. The console message is displayed **twice**!?

I guess that something related to the *caching mechanism* is going on here, but since the message is supposed to be **appended** why it isn't displayed twice as the console message?

Putting aside this issue, this seems to work and I wonder why it's necessary in the first place to put the React rendering after the page is loaded (without Turbolinks there was the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener)?

*I guess that this has do with unexpected rendering by javascript code executed when some DOM elements are yet to be loaded.*

Then, I tried your alternative [way using `<%= content_for … %>`/`<%= yield %>`](https://github.com/sanjibukai/react-turbolinks-test/commit/cc6f620e8e104737a14cab1e9890742766ba8d3f).
And as you expected this give mitigate results ans some weird behavior.

When I load via the URL the *index* page and then go to the *show* page using the Turbolink, it works! 

The div message as well as the console message are shown **once**.

Then if I go back (using Turbolink), the div message is gone and I got the *".. unmounted.."* console message as wanted.

But from then on, whenever I go back to the show page, the div and the console message are both **never displayed** at all.

 The only message that's displayed is the *".. unmounted.."* console message whenever I go back to the *index* page.

Worse, if I load the *show* page using the URL, the div message is **not** displayed anymore!? The console message is displayed but I got an error regarding the *div* element (`Cannot read property 'appenChild' of null`).

*I will not deny that I completely ignore what's happening here..*

Lastly, I tried your last *best advice* and simply put the [last code snippet in the HTML head](https://github.com/sanjibukai/react-turbolinks-test/commit/6384104e39ff2c4840d06ed55815298b84fbc16e).

Since this is `jsx` code, I don't know how to handle it within the Rails asset pipeline / file structure, so I put my `javascript_pack_tag` in the html `head`.
And indeed, this works **well**.

This time the code is executed *everywhere* so it makes sense to use page-specific element (as previously intended in the commented code).

The downside, is that this time the code could be messy unless I put all page-specific code inside `if` statements that test for the presence of the page-specific element.

However since Rails/Webpack has a good code structure, it should be easily manageable to put page-specific code into page-specific `jsx`files.

Nevertheless the benefit is that this time all the page-specific parts are rendered at the same time as the whole page, thus avoiding a display glitch that occurs otherwise.

I didn't address this issue at the first place, but indeed, I would like to know how to get page specific contents rendered at the same time as the whole page.

I don't know if this is possible when combining Turbolink with React (or any other framework).

But in conclusion I leave this question for later on.

Thank you for your contribution Dom..